# Mean preserving spread vs higher variance

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, economics

In the [Wikipedia article for mean-preserving spread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-preserving_spread), the following is claimed without citation:

> If B is a mean-preserving spread of A, then B has a higher variance than A; but the converse is not in general true, because the variance is a complete ordering while ordering by mean-preserving spreads is only partial.

My intuition about the very meaning of "B is a mean-preserving spread of A" has been that the B distribution enjoys the same mean but a higher variance than A. I usually think of this as a risk-averse individual preferring the certainty of winning a dollar to a $.001$ chance of winning $1,000. In my mind, the individual would rank lotteries A and B as follows:

1. Comparing the means of A and B
2. Comparing the variances of A and B

And if 1 and 2 turn out to be equal, then the risk-averse individual is indifferent between A and B. But according to this article, that is false. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of two distributions with the same mean that are incomparable with respect to the partial order "is a mean-preserving spread of" but have different variances is furnished by a first distribution that has discrete probabilities $1/2$ at $-1$ and $1/4$ each at $+1\pm\epsilon_1$ and a second distribution that has discrete probabilities $1/2$ at $+1$ and $1/4$ each at $-1\pm\epsilon_2$, with $\epsilon_1\lt\epsilon_2\lt1$. The mean in both cases is $0$, the second distribution has a higher variance than the first distribution, but you cannot obtain the second distribution from the first distribution by spreading, since there's no way to get rid of the probability at $+1+\epsilon_1$ by spreading without spreading some of it even further away from $+1$.

Comment: Edit: Can you clarify why you chose these particular distributions to illustrate your example? Do you mean there is no way to transform or produce a map from the first distribution into the second?

Comment: Alternatively, the significance of choosing the same example as you provided, except with both of the $\frac{1}{2}$ probabilities at $+1$?

Comment: This is a counterexample, so he is choosing two distributions, but one has a higher variance than the other. However, it is not true that the second one is a mean preserving spread of the first one. The definition of mean preserving spread (MPS) is that that A is a MPS of B if there is some zero-mean random variable, C, such that $A=B+C$. As you can see, the mean of A and B are the same, but at least some realization of of B is spread (B and C can bee correlated, so not every outcome will be necessarily spread).

Comment: Therefore if you modify the example so that the 1/2 mass is on +1  for both distributions, the second one is indeed a mean preserving spread of the second one. Since C can take the value of $\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1$ whenever the first random variable taks the value of $-1+\epsilon_1$ and the value of $\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2$ wheneveer the first random variable taks the value of $-1-\epsilon_1$.

Comment: @Regio: I don't think $B$ and $C$ can be correlated – at least if you mean linearly correlated. According to [the Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-preserving_spread) of a mean-preserving spread, we must have $E[C|B]=0$, and unless I'm mistaken, that implies $E[BC]=E[E[BC|B]]=E[BE[C|B]]=0=E[B]E[C]$, the absence of (linear) correlation. They can be dependent, but that's not enough; they'd have to be correlated in order to prevent the spread beyond $+1+\epsilon_1$.

Comment: @joriki You are right, Thank you for pointing it out. So this means that my second comment suggesting is wrong, even if both random variables had the 1/2 mass on the same point, say +1, but different dispersion on the other point, it will still be a good counter-example, right?

Comment: @Regio: No, it just means that you can't get the spread as easily as you suggested, using correlated variables. But you can do it with uncorrelated variables: To $-1+\epsilon_1$ add $\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1$ with probability $\frac{\epsilon_2+\epsilon_1}{2\epsilon_2}$ and $-\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1$ with probability $\frac{\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1}{2\epsilon_2}$ (and analogously for $-1-\epsilon_1$); this preserves the conditional mean as required but increases the dispersion from $\epsilon_1$ to $\epsilon_2$.

Comment: In the Wikipedia article there's an interesting characterization of mean-preserving spreads in terms of cumulative distribution functions that also shows that this must be possible.